# Mercurial push not working

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I've used push to push few files to a remote repository (using SSH).

After pushing I get

```
denis@ubuntu:/var/www/mar$ hg push
pushing to ssh://denis@medsecop.com//var/www/vhosts/medsecop.com/stage/symphony
searching for changes
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 1 changesets with 2 changes to 2 files
```

HG says 2 changes to 2 files.

But when I log into my server (the remote to which I pushed) the files aren't there (nor changed).

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`push` command doesn't change the state of local files.

After you pushed it there you need to perform `hg up` (in the remote repository directory on the server) to switch your code to the latest branch's revision.

Also this can be done by hook, and I'm sure you could google for it :-)